# Selecting minumum value applying complex creteria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question that difficult to explain. I want to compare models of the same car with each other but I have three criteria:

First: I wanna compare baseline with different models of the same car. In my dataset, baseline indicates if Car= Model. For instance, In this case first three observations are baseline and also 6th, 7th and 8th observervations

Second: I am not interested in comparing BMW X5 with another BMW X5 or with X6, and also baselines with each other

Third: It doesn't matter which speed test I am coparing. For instance, I can compare speed_test_1 of for observation with speed_test_3 of th observation

Forth: I wanna get the minimum difference across different speed tests that not equals to zero

```
Index      Car         Model   Speed_test_1   Speed_test_2 Speed_test_3
0          BMW         BMW      13               23          14
1          BMW         BMW      23               29          27
2          BMW         BMW      12               23          45
3          BMW         X5       32               15          63
4          BMW         X5       35               23          23 
5          BMW         X6       33               24          14 
6          Fiat        Fiat     23               23          24
7          Fiat        Fiat     22               25          24
8          Fiat        Fiat     23               23          21
9          Fiat        P_2      28               29          30
10         Fiat        p_3      29               28          33
```

Just to give an example: The minimum distance I get for Fiat is Fiat(index =7 ; speed_test_2 = 25) - Fiat(index = 9 ; speed_test_1= 28 ) or it can be Fiat(index = 10 ; speed_test_2 = 28 ). It could be Fiat(index= 6: speed_test_1) - Fiat(index= 7: speed_test_3) but please recall that I don't compare baselines with each other

resulting output should look like:

```
Car    Baseline    min
BMW    BMW          1   
Fiat   Fiat         3
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind how you got your output? Why is Fiat Fiat not 1? And why are there only two rows.

Comment: When Fiat = Fiat or BMW= BMW  it means that it uses the first version of engine, I wanna compare it with the newer versions. Therefore I don't compare Fiat-Fiats with Fiat_Fiat but only with Fiat-P_2 or Fiat_P_3. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define a function to find min diff according to the conditions listed in the question.
def find_min(x):
    base = x.iloc[:,-3:].astype(float).values
    others = df.loc[(df.Car==min(x.Car))&(df.Model!=min(x.Model))].iloc[:,-3:].astype(float).values
    min_diff = np.min(np.where(abs(base[:,None]-others)==0, np.inf, abs(base[:,None]-others)))
    return min_diff

#apply the function to each Car-Model Baseline group to get non-0 mins.
df.loc[df.Car==df.Model].groupby(['Car','Model']).apply(lambda x: find_min(x))
Out[1405]: 
Car   Model
BMW   BMW      1.0
Fiat  Fiat     3.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but baseline is not always located at the first three locations always. Another point is actually these distances represent string distances rather than numeric ones so taking minimum of each row first then calculating the differences may not work :/

Comment: It's fine baseline is not at the the first 3 locations because the code will find the baseline rows. As long as the test scores are in the last 3 columns it should be fine.  If the scores are not numeric, you need to convert them to numeric first but please make sure all of them can be converted to valid numbers. I've updated the answer to do the conversion. Please try again.